# Access returns strange output vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm facing a bit confusing problem Don't know what's going on. I have two windows form 1. sales 2. pending payment. This both form work almost same just a little bit change is in sales I'm calling for the all sales of the day and in pending payment I'm calling all the pending payment group by customer name. Here problem is when I open form sales it works fine but after that in pending payment it gives me same output as sales form even the query is different and same with pending payment if I open it as soon as application run it will runs perfectly but then gives same output in sales form. Here I'm attaching code of both

Code of Sales form

```
Public Sub call_data(ByVal str As String)
    'Try
        Dim totalsales As Integer
        Dim totalincome As Integer
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()

        ds.Clear()
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, cn)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(ds, "invoice")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables("invoice").Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(2).ToString(), ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(1).ToString(), ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(0).ToString(), Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(8).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(9).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(10).ToString()), Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(11).ToString()))
            totalsales += Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(8).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(9).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(10).ToString())
            totalincome += Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(11).ToString())
        Next
        Label2.Text = totalsales
        Label5.Text = totalincome
        Label7.Text = totalsales - totalincome

    ' Catch ex As Exception

   ' End Try


End Sub

Private Sub add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add.Click
    call_data("SELECT * from [invoice] Where [invoice_date] Between #" & from_date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & To_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#")
End Sub
```

Code of Pending payment form

```
Public Sub call_data(ByVal str As String)
    Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Dim totalpurchase As Integer
        Dim totalpaid As Integer
        Dim totalpending As Integer
        ds.Clear()
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(ds, "invoice")
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables("invoice").Rows.Count - 1
            totalpurchase = Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(1).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(2).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(3).ToString())
            totalpaid = Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(4).ToString())
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(0).ToString(), totalpurchase, ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(4).ToString(), totalpurchase - totalpaid)
        Next



    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add.Click
    call_data("SELECT client_name, Sum(invoice.freight_rate) AS SumOffreight_rate, Sum(invoice.total_basic_amount) AS SumOftotal_basic_amount, Sum(invoice.delivery_rate) AS SumOfdelivery_rate, Sum(invoice.advanced_amount) AS SumOfadvanced_amount FROM invoice GROUP BY invoice.client_name")
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using the same data adapter for both forms?  Not seeing a declaration.  Also wondering if you might be better served to have a invoice and pending payment table in your dataset.  And you could find some benefits to using data binding to connect your dataset to the data grid view rather than creating rows manually

Comment: Yes I have created dataadapter in da in anotherdbconfig.vb file. Should I create anotehr table for pending amount?? but this works for me that's why not creating another table

Comment: Separate data adapters, separate tables in dataset.  Your two forms show different data so should have different backing.  Also avoid using global data adapters and database connections or this type of problem will always come back

Comment: I Just seperated data adapters but still the same issue. System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' in totalpurchase = Convert.ToInt64(dssales.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(1).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(2).ToString()) + Convert.ToInt64(ds.Tables("invoice").Rows(i)(3).ToString()) this line this error comes up when it starts getting value from previous query which is called in sales form